# Jquery multiselect is not working dynamically onchange

Tags: jquery

```
<form:select id="businesstype" name="businesstype" path="businesstype"  >
  <c:forEach  items="${businesstype}" var="items">
    <option value="${items.businessTypeMstrId}" >"${items.businessTypeName}"     </option>
</c:forEach>
</form:select>

<select  id="stateId" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="">Select State</option> 
</select>
<script>





$("select#businesstype").change(function(){
            $.getJSON("reguser/loadStates",{countryId: 2}, function(j){
                //alret(j);
                 var options = '';
                 for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                   //options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
                   options += '<option value="' + j[i]+ '">' + j[i] + '</option>';
                  // alert(j[i]);

                   var option = document.createElement("option");
                  option.text = j[i];
                  // option.value = j[i];
                   var select = document.getElementById("productSelect");
                   select.appendChild(option);
                   alert(select);


                 }
                 $('stateId').empty().append('<option value=1>My option</option><option value=1>My option77</option>'); //This line is not working

               });


           });

</script>
```

Hi, I am new to jQuery my below code does not work when I give it inside a jQuery event, but it work when I give it inside JavaScript without any jQuery event. My complete code as mention above.

```
$('stateId').empty().append('<option value=1>My option</option><option value=1>My option77</option>'); //This line is not working
```

Comment: not working means change event is not getting fired, is that?

Comment: $('stateId')  suppose to be Class or ID $('#stateId')  or $('.stateId')

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the document ready code:

```
$(function() { //<-- missing this
  $("#businesstype").change(function(){
    //
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

change event get fired and Ajax response also I get correctly. But that ajax response I want to add to next multiselect dropddown I have written as below line in change event.

```
 $('#stateId').empty().append(options); //This line is not working
```

But my ajax response does not add in this multiselect dropdown. I am using following API.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/multiSelect/js/bootstrap-2.3.2.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/multiSelect/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js">   </script>
```

expected output of this code that it will create checkbox under the dropdown. (for multi select)

If I write this code outside the change event I get expected result. But I need ajax response should add on change of first dropdown.